# Flask SQLAlchemy - lazy load results

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

I have a comments table what is linked to blog post. For each comment in the database table it is listed as it's own row on the template. I would like to lazy load each comment so users browsers don't need to load thousands of comments in their browsers.

Is this what SQLAlchemy's lazy='dynamic' does? The docs confuse me on the subject of lazy and eager loading. I am only use to using lazy load libraries to lazily load images. I am new to Python, Flask and SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Yes and no. You are on the correct path in that `lazy='dynamic'` is for handling large collections. What it does is that it replaces the collection that would hold the related instances with a `Query` that allows filtering and slicing (and appending and removing). Note that this precludes eager loading strategies. How you'd use that to fetch a limited amount of comments at a time for display is up to you.

Comment: are you iterating on the comments from the results of a query or from an orm relationship collection?

Comment: I really have no idea what you mean by that @TheArchitect - something along the lines of "query(Comments).yield_per(5)" type of thing?

Answer (score 0):

If per your comment, you're loading the comments via a query with yield_per, the lazy attribute is somewhat irrelevant as it applies to entity relationship mapping (e.g. if you were loading posts which each had their own comments mapped as a relationship attribute).

Unless you're planning to stream the comments over an HTTP connection that you will keep open, I'm not sure yield_per is the best choice.
An easiest solution would be to leverage http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/api/#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.Pagination where you initially load the first page of comments, e.g. 25. Then upon a js scrolling event, kick an ajax call kicking the same query asking for page 2, and so on.

Hope it helps.